# VBA Textbox Add Unit After Inputing Number

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have a textbox in the spreadsheet for users to type in their weight. I wanted to have the unit (kg) added to the end of the number after they finished typing.

I have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

        TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "#kg")
        
End Sub
```

I know the code doesn't work because the unit will appear when the change happens which makes them only able to type the first number and will jump to the end of kg.

I am a new VBA user and don't know much coding. Is there a way to make the kg appears only after they finish typing so that it won't mess up their typing? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the unit of measure in an extra field? And in case it is always `kg` just add an label to the textfield. Why bother with adding `#kg` to the value? At the end you probably need to convert the data to double again anyway. In other words you would remove `#kg` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AfterUpdate()` event

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.TextBox1 = Me.TextBox1 & " Kg."
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, nothing happened after I typed the number. When does the event AfterUpdate () occur?

Comment: After finishing entering number hit enter from keyboard.

Comment: Still nothing happened after hitting enter. Am I correct using activeX control textbox?